# is their any grammar file of flex/bison input file in flex/bison format?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, bison, yacc, ebnf

i would like to write a flex and bison which will generate pure-cpp header file so that can platform independ.
actually i have written some code of them.

i parse the flex and bison input file using some string trick.

what i have done is that i wrote a parser by hand.
the parser is work for some file, but is buggy for other format.

suddenly i realized that the flex and bison input parse is a task that can be done in flex and bison too.

so the question is, is their anyone have done such thing, which is writing the flex and bison input file grammar in flex/bison format?

i searched in google and not get one, so, is their some reason that the flex/bison input file format is not suitable for flex/bison grammar format?

from the rici comment, i find this answer:

1. pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html. You can't just feed it into bison/flex, but it's a good start.
2. the flex input format is not really suitable for flex-style tokenisation;

Comment: Bison uses Bison to bootstrap. http://ftp.wayne.edu/gnu/bison/ It's not clear what if any are semantic predicates vs tree construction after-parse semantics. I converted the .y grammar to straight-up, action-free EBNF as an Antlr grammar for conversions. I don't remember what version I started from. https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.TrashBase/tree/main/supported_grammars/bison  Flex is an entirely different beast, where actions are wrapped up with rules way too much. So, extracting lexer grammars from a .l file is much harder, and so I have not looked at it much.

Comment: There's a grammar for Posix yacc syntax in the Posix document, at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html. You can't just feed it into bison/flex, but it's a good start. However, it doesn't include any bison extensions. Ironically, the flex input format is not really suitable for flex-style tokenisation; flex is bootstrapped but the scanner.l file is really not a good example of how to write tokenisers (IMHO). There's an accompanying grammar file, which is not so bad but has a lot of embedded actions.